# Why will indexOf() not return the location of an email address in the array?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I have an array of email addresses that I obtained using .getViewers() from my sheet. This gives me the array of

> [xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org, /hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org, testemail3@googlemail.com, testemail2@gmail.com, testemail1@gmail.com]
>
> > Note: xxxxxxx replacing sensitive information

I am trying to remove the following from that array and then send an email to the remaining email addresses.

> xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org -and- /hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org

The index results always come back as -1 (no match found).

I'm new to coding so I'm sure it is an easy fix that I am just not aware of. I have tried putting my search term in 'single' quotes, in "double" quotes, and in no quotes at all. I tried assigning it to a variable and then using the variable in the indexOf(variable). I've watch 3 different tutorials on using indexOf() that do not indicate that I should have any trouble.

```
var viewers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getViewers();
  Logger.log(viewers);

  var index = viewers.indexOf('/hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org');
  Logger.log(index);

  viewers.splice( index, 1);
  Logger.log(viewers);

  var index = viewers.indexOf('xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org');
  Logger.log(index);

  viewers.splice( index, 1);
  Logger.log(viewers);

  var string = ""+viewers;
  Logger.log(string);


  GmailApp.sendEmail(string, 'Test Treacker', 'This is the outcome from the test tracker');
```

Results I have been getting from the log:

- index = -1.0
- index = -1.0
- string = xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org,/hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org,testemail3@googlemail.com,testemail2@gmail.com

What I expect to get:

- index = 0
- index = 1
- string = testemail3@googlemail.com,testemail2@gmail.com

Comment: The values you are searching for: `/hd/domain/xxxxx.org` and `xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org` don't match the values in your array: `/hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org` (more `x`'s) and `xxxxxjrhigh@questac.org` (`questac`, not `xxxxxxx`)

Comment: The xxxxx is just to take the place of information that is sensitive. I actually didn't even count the numbers of x I put in there. I guarantee that in the original code, the searched for items exactly match the items in the array. I know this because I actually added them to the code by copy/pasting them from the array log. Thank you Nick, though. I changed them so they do match now. It was a good point.

Comment: If it isn't a typo in the strings, I can only imagine perhaps you haven't gotten your data yet by the time you attempt to find these indexes (though I don't know anything about `google-sheets`). The finding of indexes and splicing seems like it should work like you intend.

Comment: Please replace your `indexOf/splice` logic with this, and see if it works then: `const string = viewers.filter( viewer => /.com$/.test( viewer ) ).join();`

Comment: I am actually logging out the data before running the indexOf(), and the data array is successfully logging, so I don't think that is the issue. Is there some kind of type mismatch? It seems like everything here should be strings.

Comment: The code works as posted, in that if you set `viewers` to `["xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxx.org,/hd/domain/xxxxx.org,testemail3@googlemail.com,testemail2@gmail.com".split(',');`, and look for the index of an email address in the list, the code finds  them and removes them from the array. Try creating a cut down version that reproduces the problem in the post itself.

Comment: Is there some problem with indexOf() not working because of @ . or / causing it to not read them correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look at what `getViewers()` call returns here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#getviewers. It is not an array of strings, but rather an array of `User` objects, each of which has a `getEmail()` method. The reason why your `indexOf()` returns a -1 for every email is that you are not working with an array of simple strings here!

To remove two users from the array based on their email you could do something like this:

```
const viewers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getViewers();
const filteredViewers = viewers.filter(viewer =>
    viewer.getEmail() !== 'email1' && viewer.getEmail() !== 'email2');
```

Where `email1` and `email2` are emails of users you don't want to have in your resulting array.

Comment: Does the syntax error say anything specific? `const` shouldn't cause any trouble here, but you can safely replace them with `var` if you wish.

Comment: It does not say anything specific, but I changed both "const" to "var" and still got the syntax error on this line: var filteredViewers = viewers.filter(viewer => viewer.getEmail() !== 'xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org1' && viewer.getEmail() !== '/hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org');

Comment: The code uses arrow functions which are only available from ES6 upward. Try to replace that line with following code: `var filteredViewers = viewers.filter(function(viewer) {
    return viewer.getEmail() !== 'email1' && viewer.getEmail() !== 'email2';
});`

Comment: @ajobi `filter` is available. `=>` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ajobi for pointing me in the right direction. While your code didn't help me because of the odd syntax error, your revelation that the items in my viewers array where accounts instead of actual email addresses got me thinking and doing a little more research. I stumbled on an answer that works for me.

I mapped the array of accounts to change it to an array of actual email addresses. This is what I came up with.

```
function correctEmails() {

 var viewers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getViewers();
 Logger.log(viewers);

 var viewers1 = viewers.map(getEmails);

 Logger.log(viewers1);

 var index = viewers1.indexOf('/hd/domain/xxxxxxx.org');
 Logger.log(index);

 viewers1.splice( index, 1);
 Logger.log(viewers1);

 var index = viewers1.indexOf('xxxxxjrhigh@xxxxxxx.org');
 Logger.log(index);

 viewers1.splice( index, 1);
 Logger.log(viewers1);

 var string = ""+viewers1;
 Logger.log(string+" - string");


//  GmailApp.sendEmail(string, 'Test Treacker', 'This is the outcome from the test tracker');
//  

}

function getEmails(item) {
 return item.getEmail();
}
```

This results in the string I was looking for of testemail3@googlemail.com,testemail2@gmail.com and it will work no matter what order the email accounts are in.

Thanks!

Comment: congratulations to making it work (I noticed just today that you responded in a standalone answer), if you think my answer helped you solve the problem, don't forget to mark it as the correct one! =)

Comment: Your answer was not actually correct because there was some kind of syntax error I could not solve, but I definitely up-voted it for you! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction so I could find an answer that does work. You were very helpful, but if I mark it as correct and it doesn't work, I will lose reputation...you understand.

Comment: Also, the code is perfectly valid, it is just that it uses the ES6 syntax. Your syntax error is caused probably by your IDE which is not set-up to recognize ES6. That is something that is hard to foresee just from the content of the question of course. You could look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp to understand better what is all that "ES6" about. Specifically you can scroll to the "Arrow Functions" section - that is what I used in my code example.